# new to coffeescript, getting spawn ENOENT error when running cakefile

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am very new to Coffee-script. I am trying to compile using "cake build" command.

I am getting this error.

events.js:72
throw er;

Error: spawn ENOENT
      at errnoException (child_process:980:11)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)

Here is the Cake file & I am running on windows-7

```
fs    = require 'fs'
path  = require 'path'
spawn = require('child_process').spawn
hamlc = require('haml-coffee')

ROOT_PATH           = __dirname
COFFEESCRIPTS_PATH  = path.join(ROOT_PATH, '/src')
JAVASCRIPTS_PATH    = path.join(ROOT_PATH, '/build')

log = (data)->
console.log data.toString().replace('\n','')

runCmd = (cmd, args, exit_cb) ->
ps = spawn(cmd, args)
ps.stdout.on('data', log)
ps.stderr.on('data', log)
ps.on 'exit', (code)->
if code != 0
  console.log 'failed'
else
  exit_cb?()

coffee_available = ->
present = false
process.env.PATH.split(':').forEach (value, index, array)->
present ||= path.exists("#{value}/coffee")

  present

 if_coffee = (callback)->
 unless coffee_available
 console.log("Coffee Script can't be found in your $PATH.")
 console.log("Please run 'npm install coffees-cript.")
 exit(-1)
 else
 callback()

task 'build_haml', 'Build HAML Coffee templates', ->
if_coffee -> 
runCmd(path.join(path.dirname(require.resolve("haml-coffee")), "bin/haml-coffee"), 
  ["-i", "views", "-o", "build/templates.js", "-b", "views"])

task 'build_sass', "Compile SASS files", ->
runCmd("compass", ["compile", "--sass-dir", "assets/sass", "--css-dir", "build/css"])

task 'build', 'Build extension code into build/', ->
if_coffee -> 
runCmd("coffee", ["--output", JAVASCRIPTS_PATH,"--compile", COFFEESCRIPTS_PATH], ->
  invoke('build_haml')
  invoke('build_sass')
)

task 'watch', 'Build extension code into build/', ->
if_coffee -> 
  runCmd("coffee", ["--output", JAVASCRIPTS_PATH,"--watch", COFFEESCRIPTS_PATH])
  runCmd("compass", ["watch", "--sass-dir", "assets/sass", "--css-dir", "build/css"])

task 'test', ->
if_coffee -> 
runCmd("mocha", ["--compilers", "coffee:coffee-script", "tests/"])
```

Comment: do you have some source js that you are converting to coffee?

Answer (score 1):

Your indents are off.

```
log = (data)->
console.log data.toString().replace('\n','')
```

Translates to:

```
var log;    
log = function(data) {};    
console.log(data.toString().replace('\n', ''));
```

Function bodies should be indented 2 spaces:

```
log = (data)->
  console.log data.toString().replace('\n','')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. although Indentation looks fine to me. may be it got disturbed when I was copying file here. Here is the exact file.  http://fpaste.org/41077/98767137/

Comment: which runCmd is failing?

Comment: I understand that but saying "there is an error somewhere in here" is not helping. It will help if you can figure out which runCmd is failing. Try adding in logging before every call to runCmd. Or pull up the generated js file and figure out which line in the coffee source is failing.

Comment: @jcollum I am having the same problem. I am running OSX, can you tell me how to add loggin? or can I print to console while execution?

Comment: @shshank Winston is a good logging library. But for a small program like this I'd just do `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

@user2475624

the reason you are getting the error is because you dont have compass installed. If you have ruby installed try this,

```
gem install compass
```

or

```
sudo gem install compass
```

Comment: I don have ruby installed. Although I tried npm install compass. But again no luck.

Comment: npm works, even npm -g works.. but yet compass is not in the path.

get ruby and then install compass, the build process will work..

Comment: Did the answer help you? Would you accept the answer if it did?